# SharePoint integration outside farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, rest, integration

Can someone provide me an overview of the **possible ways of interaction with SharePoint from an external source**.

For example add items to a list from an application **not running in the farm**.

In a farm application I can use *Client Object Model ( C# or JS)*.

From the "outside" I can use Rest API and what else?

Are the *web services deprecated* in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET (asmx) web services, and direct Remote Procedure Calls (RPC) calls to the owssvr.dll file are deprecated, but are still supported in the SharePoint 2013 framework for backward compatibility.

I think you have to use REST API.

[Choose the right API set in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: and what about client object model? Can I reference the DLL and use it?

Comment: Yes, Client Object model for management code was created for application outside the farm. Add references to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll and you can write custom client application